# Windows Server 2008, can't get a dynamic previously mirrored disk to boot

Tags: windows

I have a Windows 2008 installation that will no longer boot.

The server had 2 disks in software RAID using the operating system.

One disk failed and was removed and I was able to boot again using the mirrored option on the boot options.

At that point I was unable to back up - and I altered the 100MB system reserved partition based on some searching on forums.

The server now fails to boot.

I tried using bootrec to fix the boot but this did not work.

I then used gparted to make the main Windows partition bootable, which has not resolved.

I have also used startrep.exe when booting from a Windows disk with no success.

I now have a "dynamic" disk with a full Windows installation on it which will not boot.

The disk has three partitions (1MB, 465GB (the windows partition), and 100MB).

I have no system back up.

Comment: I imagine the Windows Recovery Console and fixmbr / fixboot might save you here.

Comment: Fixmbr reports success but fixboot fails and the scan fails to see the operating system is there. Only 2 volumes are shown in do running from the cd. One is the cd and the other is the large partition

Comment: Before making too much change on the disk, did you took a clone or it while you can read it ?

Comment: Copied all the files but couldn't do a system backup

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a windows installation CD or USB drive.

When setup screen shows up, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open command prompt.

Enter `Diskpart`, then make sure System Reserved volume has no drive letter assigned to it, then mark it as active (Diskpart command `ACTIVE`)
Also make sure windows' drive is assigned to drive letter `C:`.
exit diskpart.

Now run the following:

`bootsect /nt60 ALL`

`bootrec /fixmbr`

`bootrec /fixboot`

`bootrec /rebuildbcd`

reboot the PC